# Machine Learning python code for reading file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to use machine learning Random Forest for regression problem. I am using python 3.x, and the packages numpy, matplotlib and pandas are already installed on my computer.

I am using the exact same 11 first lines of the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miI9rwH4Y4g).

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('testFile.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values
```

I am having the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Cours\****************************************\RandomForestRegressionTest.py", line 9, in <module>
    y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1367, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1737, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 204, in _has_valid_tuple
    if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1672, in _has_valid_type
    return self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1713, in _is_valid_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Any help ???

Thank you

Comment: Please paste the code that you're running.

Comment: I have added the code. It is exactly the same as the code of the video

Comment: For the future, please try using tags more wisely; question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `numpy` (removed) - it is actually a pure `pandas` question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the csv file. I edited the csv file using Notepad++, and changed all the ";" to "," and it works.
It is weird because every csv file use ";" separator not ",".

I am surprised, but also happy because I found the error (wierd error).

Comment: CSV stands for "Comma Separated Values". CSV does not use a semicolon as the separator.

Comment: @David this is not true; CSV loosely means delimited text files, even with other field delimiters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: Sorry, I should have said default separator. If someone did not specify, comma separated would naturally be assumed. The poster saying that CSV always uses semicolon is flat wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should try editing your csv file. Save it with csv format and upload it in the notebook. If it is in excel format you can use
`pd.read_xlsx('filename.xlsx')`